# How to vote? Is this really too broad?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-reopen

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19643996/major-differences-between-ruby-and-r-syntax) is currently in the reopen queue. And I'm really not sure how to vote. At the first look it indeed seems very broad, but as correctly pointed out by the OP, [in this, very similar, question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017990/what-are-the-major-differences-and-similarity-in-java-and-ruby) a concrete and apparently useful answer was possible. What do you think?

**Update:**

According to the definition, a question is *too broad* if:

> could be answered by an entire book, or has many valid answers, it's probably too broad for our format

And when:

> There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow down the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

In the second example, the accepted answer is neither long nor one of many possible. It seems the only way to correctly point out (almost?) all of the key differences between the languages.

Comment: This is going to be mildly ironic if the other question ends up getting closed too for being too broad.

Comment: @DennisMeng Indeed, that's what I wanted to do when I saw it :) Until I saw the accepted answer.

Comment: What seems certain that either both should be opened, or both closed.

Comment: I can agree on that point.

Comment: I love how one of the answers on the second example essentially says "I could write a book about this" as the answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both of those questions are too broad.

Remember that Stack Overflow's standards have changed over the years. In 2010, that sort of question was more acceptable. Now, they are definitely not. These are canonical examples of "too broad" questions.

---

Edit: To address the second question, I'd like to point out that the list the answerer provided is not actually a complete list. While the author of this particular question may have found it helpful, the answer itself was not necessarily *guaranteed* to be so for its accuracy.

In other words, the answerer took a guess at some of the things the author might have been interested in, and happened to be correct.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please also take into account my update of the question?

Comment: @Bartosz How do you define what a "key" or "major" difference is though? One person may not care about a certain feature, but it may be considered vitally important to another. That list-as-an-answer is likely extremely incomplete and are the major similarities and differences *to that user*.

Comment: @animuson Good point! I wanted to play the role of advocatus diaboli, but I've deleted what I had written :) Thanks!

Comment: @BartoszKP Modified.

Comment: This question is also very broad: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113611/what-does-ruby-have-that-python-doesnt-and-vice-versa?rq=1

Comment: @histelheim That question is also locked: `This question exists because it has historical significance, but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here.`

Comment: Here's another one that is probably too broad: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901314/what-are-the-major-differences-between-php-and-ruby?rq=1 as well as this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936085/what-are-the-major-differences-between-python-and-php?rq=1

Comment: @histel Please flag these questions; there isn't much I can personally do.