# Can we get more recognition for canonical questions?

Tags: discussion, multiple-questions, too-broad

I've only asked one *very broad* question (according to popular consensus, and I agree, though it seems to now get upvotes for some reason), and it is on Stack Overflow: [How could I generate and execute machine code at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43255053/how-can-i-dynamically-create-and-execute-machine-code-at-runtime)

A [similar meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203348/267500) asking whether or not a particular set of questions is too broad references [help/closed-questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions), which states:

> too broad - if your question could be answered by an entire book, or has many valid answers (but no way to determine which - if any - are correct), then it is probably too broad for our format
>
> > Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

It is quite clear from this definition and the answer provided in the meta post linked above that being too broad is unacceptable here at Stack Exchange, however, it is not very clear as to what is or is not considered too broad, and I believe there may be questions that, although they fit this description of being *Too broad*, they do, however, have an answer that can work for other questions of the same nature.

For example, [this canonical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25110510/why-doesnt-css-feature-work-in-browser-but-works-in-others?noredirect=1&lq=1) as a "canonical duplicate" for very similar CSS questions of the same format. It also makes it quite clear, with a disclaimer,

> This is the canonical duplicate for all questions solvable completely by adding vendor prefixes. Stack Overflow questions should not be this broad unless discussed on meta and a canonical answer created thereafter like [this one was](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267634/what-to-do-with-css-prefix-questions).

If there exists a sufficiently broad question, but its answer and question are sufficient for all esoteric questions of the same nature, should not this format of questions be permissible for all Stack Exchange websites? I believe a change that better distinguishes and clearly defines what exactly a canonical question is and facilitates their creation and dissemination amongst non-canonical questions, or if that is not possible, an official clarification in the help section, would benefit the Stack Exchange community.

## Criteria

I believe the best criteria for a question with this nature must answer yes to each the following:

1. This question does not fall under the category of *too broad* as defined in the [help/closed-questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) page, or the question *does fall* under this category, but has sufficient evidence to suggest or prove that this question can be answered comprehensively without extensive explanation and taking up no more than the length of a short to medium length article or blog post, i.e. can be answered with a short essay, but not a couple paragraphs.
2. This question has an answer that sufficiently answers every possible question for its specific category or sub-category.

## In a Different Paradigm

The [Documentation trial](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation) ended for various reasons, but these types of questions described here in this meta question are not the same, although they are similar in nature to how the Documentation questions work. They are different primarily in the sense that these questions are not intended to document a certain feature, nor does the nature of these questions intend to be "as broad as possible for a specific subset of questions", but are best defined as:

> To describe, as *fundamentally as possible*, without ambiguity, the means of accomplishing a group of related problems or tasks that require the same process.

It is to my understanding that Stack Exchange, in general, expects questions to be as specific as possible; to answer specific problems in specific scenarios that others may come across as well, regardless of the obscurity of the problem. Considering how these "*fundamentalist questions*" are meant to solve a specific problem without being ambiguous, yet acting as the abstract template to concrete children of the same problem, I believe it may also be good to separate these problems from the problems that are currently common on Stack Exchange.

I do not believe another Stack Exchange site is necessary for this, nor do I believe there needs to be a secondary site for every Stack Exchange just to separate these problems, but that these problems should be distinguished in some way and separated from the crowd, perhaps with a tag of some sort, with a description that says, when hovered: "This question is intended to solve a specific category of very similar problems."

I would also like to point out that, although the description for "too broad" states, "has many valid answers (but no way to determine which - if any - are correct)", answers are usually sorted by the community with the voting system anyways, though not always perfectly, which is often the case, or at least in terms of conflict between voting up because "it is useful" or voting up "because this answers the question". Often times, I see questions with answers that are accepted, but another highly upvoted answer directly answers the actual question, and in the comments you usually find, "Why isn't this the accepted answer?" or "This should be the accepted answer because [it answers the actual question]", and for the answer that is accepted: "Why is this the accepted answer? This doesn't explain how to solve [X] problem because it expects [Y] when this answer only explains [A through X, and Z, but not Y]!"

One idea I have for this might be to have question hierarchies wherein this question has a list of specific questions that answer your specific question. Sortition of questions that are already related is accomplished by labels, and the aside already contains similar questions, but a link to a page containing a list of questions with the same nature as the problem at hand, but answering specific audiences, might be a good approach. A top navigation could also be added, in spite of this, showing a label hierarchy or question hierarchy, for example, in the pattern:

[language-or-technology] > [feature] {> [sub-feature(s)]} > [specific-problem]

## Potential Benefits

- Such kinds of questions can help to eliminate questions that, although not considered duplicate questions, are questions with duplicate answers.
- Can reduce the number of questions necessary to arrive at a single solution, for example, if a series of questions are required to be asked to solve a fundamental question that can be asked more easily, but might be considered too broad given the current guidelines for what is and what is not an acceptable question or answer.
- Promotes higher quality answers and a greater number of answers. These kinds of fundamental problems can promote a greater number of answers because there are usually multiple approaches to a single question.
- Relating to the previous bullet point, this provides questions that benefit a greater portion of the population for the problem at hand.
- As mentioned in the summary, often the accepted answer is not the answer to the question, but answers a broader question beyond the scope, or somehow answers the question, but not as described by the question. If we allow questions of this nature, however, this will not be a problem, as anyone can state a procedure, and it can be verified (and sorted by the voting system).
- The number of duplicates and low-quality questions is already a prevalent issue on the network. Allowing for more fundamental questions can eliminate duplicates and low-quality questions by providing a solution for a variety of cases that are the same or very similar.
- Less search effort - since these questions will have a broader scope than just a specific feature, but can in fact cover a number of features, the questions linked from this question can be presented as solutions for a specific case, and this way, obscure and common answers and questions alike can be preserved and reach their appropriate audiences more effectively than they would have, as I often find myself searching through the search results quite a bit if I have a specific question, or a broader question that requires a different resource to find the answer.

## Potential Drawbacks

- A greater number of closed questions with the reason "too-broad" for the same reason that questions are commonly already being closed (failing to read and follow the Q&A guidelines for making a question or answer; these kinds of questions ought to have their own guidelines to be very clear as to what is or is not "too-broad" or "too-specific" to be labeled as a "fundamental-question"). Also due to what the community judges to be "too-broad" or "too-specific" (ah, the fault with democracy... tsk! Tsk!)
- Too many answers - while having many answers, in this case, is a good thing, duplicate answers might be a new problem introduced by this sort of question, and even having too many answers. It might simply be that a certain answer is a duplicate of another answer that is worded differently, so you end up with a subtle duplicate. A problem shouldn't have an encyclopedia of solutions.
- Inadequate answers - a question that isn't flagged or closed as "too broad" may have a few, or many, answers that do not adequately answer the question in question (heh heh) because the question may be borderline ambiguous yet specific. Such questions are more likely to have been missed by the community as needing to be flagged or closed, or need to be put on hold for further review, and common instructions (please correct the following identified errors...) to improve the question and get better results.
- Greater moderation effort; the need for more moderators - this is a new type of question with its own rules and regulations. It needs its own team of moderators or existing moderators, though not necessarily a big problem. Adding anything to anything will obviously increase the workload and the required amount of time and effort to build and maintain a service.

In summary, these questions are intended to solve non-esoteric questions that have canonical answers, or a solution to "multiple questions, one answer", that can exist alongside other questions and in current Stack Exchange sites without requiring extensive modification or development. This doesn't mean that existing, specific questions would be deleted, but simply referenced from the question. If examples are needed, I am glad to provide some in this post as real questions that would best fit this category, but would not be considered suitable for regular Stack Exchange. In one word: polychotomous.

Back to the original question then: what would be too broad a question for Stack Exchange? At what point does a question become too broad, and how might a canonical question be too broad?

*To be clear: I am asking what the limits of specificity are for any given question on Stack Exchange. I am not asking about* how to make, answer, etc. *a canonical question.*

Comment: _Too broad_ and _Primarily opinion based_ are overlapping close reasons. Just to note you.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I have to disagree. It is better to say that _Primarily opinion based_ can be considered a subset of _Too broad_, but they are still essentially different. Primarily opinion based questions can provide answers that are too broad, but the question itself may not be considered a broad question, whereas a broad question can provide opinionated answers and/or broad answers as well. A broad question doesn't have to ask for opinion.

Comment: @LinkTheProgrammer Could well be, you've hit the bias with this post as well.

Comment: @gnat I don't see how this is a duplicate of "How to approach asking and answering a canonical question?" I'm suggesting that there be a recognition of canonical questions on StackExchange in a more constructive manner; a means of facilitation for them that distinguishes them more easily than what is already possible with existing technology on SE sites.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm trying to be objective here. I do acknowledge some bias in my post, however, logic is logic, and set theory tells me that Primarily opinion based is a subset of Too broad.

Comment: I don't think you're understanding Too Broad's "has many valid answers (but no way to determine which - if any - are correct)" wording correctly. What it means is that *it is impossible to vote on the answers in such a way that the votes are correct for all the cases the question covers*. That is, the question does not have a single set of good, better, best answers, but a whole muddle of answers, some of which are great for one subset of the question, some for another, some for multiple, but none at all the best for all subsets, or even "good".

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure your title doesn't match the most important part of your question, which is probably about ways to better handle canonical questions.

Comment: @NathanTuggy then do you think I should probably update the title to better reflect this?

Comment: @LinkTheProgrammer: Definitely. I would have myself, but I wasn't quite sure what the best summary would be.

Comment: @NathanTuggy What you quoted clearly states that P != NP, err, uh, that answers that are sound or acceptable cannot be easily verified. Makes perfect sense, however, I suppose the “are correct” clause threw me off before because it was not immediately clear whether they meant the answer was correct for the question or if it is verifiably true for what it does answer. Also, supposing there’s a chance that all the combined answers give the answer, a community wiki could put them all together, though that probably rarely happens.

Comment: @NathanTuggy “Can we get more recognition for canonical questions, please?” Sound good? Unfortunately, the direction of my question changed about two paragraphs in, so the whole thing ended up diverging from the original question title.

Comment: @LinkTheProgrammer: Your new title should work fine. But I'm not sure I'm communicating clearly enough what I mean about "too broad". I don't mean that the answers to a too-broad question are difficult to verify (which is often the case for perfectly good questions), or that they are fragmented and each only answers one chunk (which is a reasonable enough thing to happen as well). Rather, the answers are addressing fundamentally different problems that have certain superficial similarities, all of which are conflated in the question. (For example, asking about a single error message.) [1/2]

Comment: @LinkTheProgrammer: If the question is really dealing with multiple essentially-different situations, the answers that are relevant or helpful for *one* of them may be completely irrelevant or even actively counterproductive for others. So the score on the different answers is basically completely incomparable: it depends, not on which answer is *best* for the *question*, but on the relative proportions of voters who had each of the various invisible sub-questions, and voted on answers accordingly. [2/2]

Comment: @NathanTuggy I think what you just described is what I would call convoluted Q&A which is the antithesis of focused Q&A.  It's why I think the first thing we should try to teach those new to the SE Network the importance of one question per question.

Answer (score 3):

The big problem here is that no one can write a canonical question.

Heck... Arguably no one can write a canonical *answer*, but you can certainly **try**: if it turns out your answer is broadly useful, then it will be widely used, widely referenced, and one can say it becomes *part of the canon.*

But there's no way to guarantee that when writing the question. You can ask - and many have - that answerers explain some huge, meaty subject... But if no one covers it satisfactorily in their answer, then all you've succeeded in writing is a tease, a click-bait question that doesn't deliver.

In short, unless you're writing answers this is entirely out of your hands - the least harm you can do is in writing specific, focused, well-researched questions, and anything short of that (or more broad than that...) is more likely to make The Internet worse than better.

But what if you *are* writing answers, and really want to write that canonical post? How can you do this if no-one's asking those broad questions? Well, [Joel wrote about this 7 years ago now](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/05/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/):

> **It is OK to edit a question to make it more general.** With the power of editing comes the power to take someone’s selfish, very specific question, and edit it a little bit until they’re asking the more general question that hundreds of people encounter. For example, if someone asks, “I set up a web server at home but I can’t access it from work,” it’s OK to rewrite the question as, “What things should I check when a web server running at home is not visible on the Internet?” In fact, sometimes selfish, stupid questions of the “do my homework” variety can be easily edited into a form where the answer will provide an extremely valuable resource for the internet at large.
>
> **Help us build a great library of canonical answers.** If you keep seeing the same form of questions, whether it’s mod_rewrite rules on Server Fault, freezing computers on Super User, or how to use regular expressions to parse HTML, write a great, canonical answer, once and for all. Make it community wiki so that as many other people as possible can make it great. Work really hard on writing something that is clear, concise, and understandable by as wide an audience as possible.

To summarize: don't *ask* broad questions; instead, *answer broadly* and then **edit the question to match!**

Answer (score 2):

I think you are proposing a complicated discussion on something that I think can be boiled down to quite a simple answer to "Just how broad is too broad for StackExchange?", at least on most SE Main sites (because some communities may provide guidelines in their Meta sites that diverge).

1. If a question asks more than one question, then it is probably too broad.
2. If a question appears likely to generate more than about five answers over time, due to its open-endedness, or it looks like a "book" would be needed to provide a single answer, then it starts to be a candidate for too broad.

The first criterion above is reasonably quantitative while the second is qualitative.

In the second criterion I say about five answers because with many more than that it is unlikely that many users will scroll past about the first five anyway, but that is not a hard and fast number.

Assessing open-endedness is somewhat subjective, but close and re-open votes are there to help communities asymptote towards what level of open-endedness they will accept before the community voting decides a question is too broad on qualitative grounds.

Comment: I would have to say that the first part of my post is explaining the question in the title, and the reasons for the next part; the next part asking for greater recognition of canonical questions which is indicated by, "should not this format of questions be permissible for all StackExchange websites?" I admit, however, that I thought more deeply about the question as I wrote the rest of the article, so there might be some in-congruence.

Comment: as clearly seen in the closed questions help page, there is no enumeration of what exactly is or is not too broad. Arguably, anything can take a book to explain, depending on who is asking, especially if you want to write a proof for why 1 + 1 = 2, but I'd rather not be left guessing. How does anyone know that something is "likely to generate [too many answers]"? And no. 1 is quite clear, but it isn't, because you find answers that have "by the way" questions which get answered alongside the main question anyways in the answers, especially if relevant to the main question.

Comment: I think that "by the way" questions should not be answered because "multiple question" questions should be closed as too broad.  When they are their askers should consider it a bonus and not a precedent for asking more such questions.

Comment: then I guess it is up to the _rest_ of the community who agree with you to fix all the questions with more than one question. That’s the problem, though. Everyone that came by didn’t bother to close as too broad. Likewise, you may as well tell everyone to only upvote a question or comment because it is considered a good, on-topic question.

Comment: I think various communities have been fixing "multiple question" questions to various degrees since not long after the early days (which for me was 2010).